# I am trying to train a CNN . Getting ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) to recognize characters from the Chars74K dataset in Python using Keras and TensorFlow.

I am getting an error at model.fit():
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Here is my code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/191VYKn64ar87oK3mkyLHFE-TW7XVBrk1?usp=sharing

I added four Conv2D layers with a MaxPool2D layer after every Conv2D layer and two hidden layers with Dropout layers in between. Ultimately I'm getting this error which I believe has something to do with the input_shape

Comment: Have you checked whether you are passing any badly formatted data?

Comment: Hi mknull. The dataset is pretty good and downloaded from kaggle.

Comment: Add a check to see if anything that you are doing affects it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually the input_shape like I mentioned. The image sizes are 128x128 px and hence input_shape has be (128,128,1). The '1' represents grayscale image.